# Limit textbox to numbers, points and decimal separators

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to limit input in a TextBox to only numbers and point `.` and only one comma `,` with decimal separator

I have tried the following:

```
char ch = e.Text[0];

if ((Char.IsDigit(ch) || ch == '.' || ch==','))
{
    //Here TextBox1.Text is name of your TextBox
    if ((ch == '.' && TextBox.Text.Contains('.')) || (ch==',' && 
                  TextBox.Text.Contains(',')))
        e.Handled = true;
}
else
    e.Handled = true;
```

but with this method can put only one point

Answer (score 1):

How about handling the `PreviewTextInput` event like this?

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.Text[0]) && e.Text[0] != '.' && (e.Text[0] != ',' || textBox.Text.Contains(","));
}
```

You may also want to handle the `Pasting` event:

```
private void TextBox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        string text = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
        bool hasComma = false;
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c != '.' && (c != ',' || hasComma))
                e.CancelCommand();
            hasComma = c == ',';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting" />
```